# Are there any good markup formats designed for console output, as opposed to HTML?

Tags: .net, markup

Think [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29), but designed with a monospaced text console in mind. I'm mainly thinking text tables, colors and indenting.

Answer (score 1):

HTML actually isn't that bad for console display. Think about the console-based [Lynx browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29).

Of course, you'd have to design the page specifically for it if you want to to look okay, and forget about most of your modern layout techniques, but it does work.